# Creating a new Index when loop finds specific String Sequence

Tags: pandas, web-scraping

I have a list of strings that are specs for a car. The different trims are smashed together though and I want the code to automatically separate them using the year as an indicator. It has to either be exactly 4 digit number or within a range of values because there are 3 digit value and 5 digit values but the year will always be 4. What code do I need to tell it to look for a 4 digit code to create a new line and then continue with the loop?

Here is the code:

```
import re
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mewspoon',
#    'From': 'mewspoon@me.com'
#}

URL = requests.get('https://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/a24847025/2018-
ford-mustang-automatic-transmission-performance/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="specs-content"):
    DataList=pd.DataFrame(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").split())

    #create file
df.to_excel('CarScrapeTest.xlsx', sheet_name='Car&Driver')
    
#File Format
df = pd.DataFrame(DataList).transpose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering you question, you can use `re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', text)` to check for a valid year. And if it maches you starts to write on anoter data frame.

Also I noted that you were trying to get the cars specs, so I wrote a litle loop that you could use to add info to a data frame then write it to csv. I used the `:` mark to separete attributes and values, and concatenated then on a df.
Cheers.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

URL = requests.get('https://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/a24847025/2018-ford-mustang-automatic-transmission-performance/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')
specifications = soup.find(class_="specs-content")

cars_specs = dict()
df = pd.DataFrame()

for paragraph in specifications.find_all('p'):
    paragraph_text = paragraph.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").strip()

    if paragraph_text == "Specifications":
        continue

    year = re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', paragraph_text)
    if year:
        if len(cars_specs) > 1:
            new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars_specs, orient='index')
            df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1, sort=False)

        cars_specs = {'Car': paragraph_text}

    else:
        specs = paragraph_text.split('\n')
        for index in range(len(specs) - 1):

            if specs[index].find(':') == len(specs[index]) - 1:
                cars_specs[specs[index].replace(':','')] = specs[index + 1]
            elif specs[index].find(':') > 1:
                inline_specs = specs[index].split(':')
                cars_specs[inline_specs[0]] = inline_specs[1]

else:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars_specs, orient='index')
    df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1, sort=False)

print(df)
df.to_csv('CarScrapeTest.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=False, sep=';')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped immensely!